# Multi-dimensional arrays in Mandrill with handlebars

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, handlebars.js, mandrill

I'm trying to loop through a multi-dimensional array to get properties of products that are part of line items. They look basically like this: (I did a json_encode so it would be easier to read)

```
[{
    "rcpt": "email@email.com",
    "vars": [{
        "name": "SYSTEM",
        "content": "Bikes"
    }, {
        "name": "CUSTOMERSERVICE",
        "content": "(855-553-4889)"
    }, {
        "name": "IMAGE",
        "content": "http:\/\/www.url.com\/assets\/images\/chicago\/email\/dear_member.jpg"
    }, {
        "name": "LINKCOLOR",
        "content": "#3db7e4"
    }, {
        "name": "FACEBOOK",
        "content": "Bikes"
    }, {
        "name": "TWITTER",
        "content": "Bikes"
    }, {
        "name": "INSTAGRAM",
        "content": "Bikes"
    }, {
        "name": "CLOSING",
        "content": "Greetings"
    }, {
        "name": "item",
        "content": [{
            "lineItem": 1,
            "id": "3",
            "name": "24-Hour Pass Gift Certificate",
            "quantity": 2,
            "nameShort": "24-Hour",
            "type": "Gift Certificate",
            "image": "24hour_blank.jpg",
            "price": "9.95",
            "total": "19.90",
            "taxable": false,
            "giftCertificates": {
                "3204": {
                    "id": "3204",
                    "redemptionNumber": "xxxxx",
                    "type": "24-Hour"
                },
                "3205": {
                    "id": "3205",
                    "redemptionNumber": "xxxxx",
                    "type": "24-Hour"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "lineItem": 2,
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Annual Membership Gift Certificate",
            "quantity": 2,
            "nameShort": "Annual",
            "type": "Gift Certificate",
            "image": "annual_blank.jpg",
            "price": "75.00",
            "total": "150.00",
            "taxable": false,
            "giftCertificates": {
                "892": {
                    "id": "892",
                    "redemptionNumber": "xxxxxx",
                    "type": "Annual"
                },
                "893": {
                    "id": "893",
                    "redemptionNumber": "xxxxx",
                    "type": "Annual"
                }
            }
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "orderID",
        "content": 1220
    }, {
        "name": "giftMessage",
        "content": false
    }, {
        "name": "email",
        "content": "email@email.com"
    }, {
        "name": "transactionDate",
        "content": "12\/23\/2015"
    }, {
        "name": "transactionTime",
        "content": "12:21 pm"
    }, {
        "name": "salesTaxTotal",
        "content": 0
    }, {
        "name": "salesTaxRatePercent",
        "content": "6.250"
    }, {
        "name": "TransactionAmount",
        "content": "169.90"
    }, {
        "name": "account_number",
        "content": "XXXX1111"
    }, {
        "name": "card_type",
        "content": "Visa"
    }, {
        "name": "firstName",
        "content": "tetete"
    }, {
        "name": "lastName",
        "content": "tethuhhu"
    }, {
        "name": "address",
        "content": "295 Place St"
    }, {
        "name": "city",
        "content": "Brooklyn"
    }, {
        "name": "state",
        "content": "NY"
    }, {
        "name": "zip",
        "content": "11238"
    }, {
        "name": "country",
        "content": "US"
    }, {
        "name": "phone",
        "content": "8888888888"
    }, {
        "name": "transactionId",
        "content": "xxxxxx"
    }, {
        "name": "shipToFirstName",
        "content": "tetete"
    }, {
        "name": "shipToLastName",
        "content": "tethuhhu"
    }, {
        "name": "shipToAaddress",
        "content": "295 Place St"
    }, {
        "name": "shipToCity",
        "content": "Brooklyn"
    }, {
        "name": "shipToState",
        "content": "NY"
    }, {
        "name": "shipToZipCode",
        "content": "11238"
    }, {
        "name": "ShipToCountry",
        "content": "US"
    }, {
        "name": "ShipToCountry",
        "content": "US"
    }]
}]
```

So I am trying to get a print out of each gift certificate's type and redemption number. When I iterate through {{ giftCertificates }} like this:

```
{{#each giftCertificates}}
    {{type}} {{redemptionNumber}}
{{/each}}
```

I get one of the line items but not the other. I'm guessing maybe it is being overwritten when it loops through again? But I have also tried to loop through {{ item }} and grab {{ giftCertificates.type }} and {{ giftCertificates.redemptionNumber }} and that does not work either. What is the correct way to get all of these from each line item?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but:

- you can use `{{this.proprietyName}}` to get the type and number:

```
{{#each giftCertificates}}
   {{this.892.type}}
{{/each}}
```

- do not forget to add this to the mandrill `message` o

```
"merge": true,
"merge_language": "handlebars",
```

Also, the data structure is not ideal:

```
giftCertificates[
    {
     "id": "892",
     "redemptionNumber": "xxxxxx",
     "type": "Annual"
    }, 
    {
     "id": "893",
     "redemptionNumber": "xxxxxx",
     "type": "Annual"
    }
]
```

would be easier to handle.